# How to embed a static struct in a Swift class?

Tags: swift, foundation

I need to observe a Unicorn class (inherits from NSObject), but for business reasons, I cannot use a proper reactive framework to have observable properties.
I have to fallback to KVO (god help me).

To make things NOT "stringly-typed", I have an idea of introducing a static property called observableKeyPaths which would provide all the keyPaths that are actually KVO-observable for the Unicorn class...using dot notation.

Let's have an example. The Unicorn class has a property `status` that can be KVOed.
Then when I would be setting up my observer, I would want to reference the keypath like this:

```
   unicornInstance.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: Unicorn.observableKeyPaths.status   ...etc..)
```

I can come up with a struct like this:

```
struct UnicornObservableKeyPaths {

    static let status = "status"
}
```

This struct can be referenced easily:

```
UnicornObservableKeyPaths.status
```

But how do I make this struct part of the class?
The following is not working for me:

```
class Unicorn {  

   dynamic private(set) var status: String

   static let observableKeyPaths: UnicornObservableKeyPaths = UnicornObservableKeyPaths()

}
```

Any ideas? What am I missing here? 
When I reference the static property..I can access this

```
Unicorn.observableKeyPaths
```

but not the `status` static member of the struct..why?

Comment: Do you know about Swift 3 `#keyPath` notation?

Comment: I do now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reference the static property because `UnicornObservableKeyPaths()` is an actual `UnicornObservableKeyPaths` and `status` is a static variable.

You can reference the struct itself using

```
static let observableKeyPaths = UnicornObservableKeyPaths.self
let _ = Unicorn.observableKeyPaths.status
```

You can just nest the struct inside of your class

```
class Unicorn : NSObject {
    dynamic private(set) var status: String = ""

    struct ObservableKeyPaths {

        static let status = "status"
    }
}
```

Your observing example would look like this:

```
let unicornInstance = Unicorn()
unicornInstance.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: Unicorn.ObservableKeyPaths.status, options: [], context: nil)
```

Comment: Sooo simple!  Just including the struct and that's it! ..I missed the struct being an instance part..my bad.